# How can I use a bridged adapter in VirtualBox

Tags: networking, virtualbox

In my VirtualBox VM's settings, I've elected to use a Bridged Adapter. When I run the VM, I expect to see this bridge show up as hardware, but I don't. How am I supposed to use this bridge? (What I ultimately want is to route all of my VM's traffic through a proxy.)

On the host, the bridge looks like this:

```bsh
# ip addr show br-e116542c68ff
278: br-e116542c68ff: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:e3:c5:2f:2c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.30.0.1/16 brd 172.30.255.255 scope global br-e116542c68ff
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:e3ff:fec5:2f2c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

On the guest (Windows), I don't see any evidence of this adapter.

```
REM getmac
Physical Address    Transport Name                                            
=================== ==========================================================
08-00-27-E6-E5-59   \Device\Tcpip_{4AA86136-917B-45D2-BE98-087B589B8CA0}      

REM ipconfig
Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c50d:519f:96a4:e108%10
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.225.8
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

And these are my VM settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bridged Adapter will get its IP from your router. I think that is why you have the 169.254 no DHCP address.

If you wish to use your own NIC, it needs to be on a USB card, and you need to use NAT in the Guest machine, and you need to enable USB pass through to be able to see the NIC and install it.

For your purpose, NAT, not Bridged is the way to set up.